# how to pass parameter to EMR job

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I have an EMR job that I run it as follows

```
/opt/emr/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOB_FLOW_ID --jar s3n://mybucket/example1.jar
```

Now I need to pass parameter to the job `maperd.job.name="My job"`
I have tried passing it via the -D flag but that did not work

`/opt/emr/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOB_FLOW_ID -Dmaperd.job.name="My job --jar s3n://mybucket/example1.jar \\ does not work`

Any idea ?

Comment: You should use your jar file locally rather than put it on S3. "--jar /your_local_path/example1.jar"

Comment: why would I do that ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283929/how-to-specify-mapred-configurations-java-options-with-custom-jar-in-cli-using