# Amazon EMR: Passing java system property to custom jar

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr, system-properties

Does Amazon EMR allow passing a system property to a custom jar, e.g. `hadoop jar -Dkey=value myjob.jar`? (`key`, `value` above used during initialization of the application itself, rather then belong to hadoop's `Configuration` object.)

The related thread [How to specify mapred configurations & java options with custom jar in CLI using Amazon's EMR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283929) discusses ways to pass system properties to hadoop daemons only via Bootstrap Actions, which, apparently, won't allow do the same for the java entry point class.

Comment: If you even somehow able to do that but the <key,value> won't be accessible from all the mappers and reducers unless you set them in the context.

Comment: That's precisely the goal.

Comment: If that's the case, please check my answer - might help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass the  to the mappers or reducers, you can do the following in the terminal or from a script -

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dkey=value"
hadoop jar ...
```

You can also put those in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh`, if you want it for every job, without explicitly defining them every time you run a job.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm rather new to EMR. When a job flow is created in EMR, one must provide a custom jar location + its arguments. At which point do we have terminal access to cluster? If so, this should be done before the job is started? Thanks,

Comment: Can you check the Bootstrap actions and see if you can pass environment variables? I think, `export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dkey=value"` is an environment variable. If you want to take direct terminal access using ssh, [you can follow this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html). Thanks

Comment: You might also [look at this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config.html)